# Vue Js Parent select option selected disabled the child select option dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

Hi I'm having this code where i have a parent select option and a child select option.

when you selected the option in the parent, the child option must be disabled.

PS. Parent select option are only clone of child option so they are having the same option

Here's my code so far.

```js
 var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
        var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");

        $dropdown1.change(function () {
            $dropdown2.empty().append($dropdown1.find('option').clone());
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            if (selectedItem) {
                $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').remove();
            }
        });

        var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                rows: []
            },
            methods: {
                addRow: function () {
                    var elem = document.createElement('tr');
                    this.rows.push({
                        title: []
                    });
                },
                removeElement: function (index) {
                    this.rows.splice(index, 1);
                },

            }
        });
```

```html
<select name="dropdown1">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>


    <div id="app">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>File</strong></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">

                    <td>
                        <select name="dropdown2">
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="1">Test 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Test 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Test 3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a v-on:click="removeElement(index);" style="cursor: pointer">Remove</a>
                    </td>


                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
            <button class="button btn-primary" v-on:click="addRow">Add row</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have a dynamic row adding with a select option inside. I wanted to disable the option of the child select option when it is selected in parent option.

For example.
Test 1 is selected in the Parent option.

The child option should also disable the Test 1 option.

And also when I add row Test 1 should be disabled.

is like disabling completely when it is selected on the parent option.

Please help.